# Error in Driver class in Java Mapreducer

Tags: java, mapreduce

I get an Error in Handling

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

How to handle it ? Can Anyone please help me...!

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
```

Above are the imported files. And error is occuring in below lines of code.

```
 job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

How to fix this issue? I am new to MapReduce.

Comment: MapReduce v2 is compatible with MapReduce v1 but class packaging is different between V2 and V1. Type `hadoop version` and report here what do you get.

Answer (score 1):

You are using few packages from updated Hadoop version[mapreduce] but few of them (TextInputFormat & TextOutputFormat) are form older version[mapred package].

It's always good to use packages from map reduce so you have to do below mention change.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

**Refer this :** https://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/hadoop-demo

I have added some working example.

Answer (score 0):

TextInputFormat and TextOutputFormat classes are from different version of hadoop as compared to other classes.Fix the imports for TextInputFormat and TextOutputFormat.